# Is there a simple (should-matchers) validation for { distinct } HABTM associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, rspec-rails, shoulda

I am trying to make my current spec more specific to test the unique/distinct-ness of Thing.Others

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :others, -> { distinct }
end

describe Thing do
  it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:others).x }
end
```

I currently have nothing in for `x`: the spec passes and I can create and save Things from another class effectively in additional specs.

When I replace `x` with `distinct`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'distinct' for #<Shoulda::Matchers::...`.

If I replace `{ distinct }` with `{ where(distinct: true) }` and put `conditions(distinct: true)` in for `x`, the validation passes, but Thing class cannot be saved properly by other specs.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what the 'x' is on line 6. As for the NoMethodError, perhaps you need to define a custom matcher or include matchers to be used in your specs in your `spec_helper` file?

Comment: I used x as a placeholder so it was easier to describe what other specs I had tried. I'm pretty new to this. Is there a convention for substitution of different code pieces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no simple shoulda-matchers validation for distinct HABTM associations. `distinct` is just one of a large family of query mechanisms that can be utilized as part of a specifying a scope and there is no explicit support for testing it in shoulda.

You're getting the `NoMethodError` because `distinct` is not an instance method of shoulda's `AssociationMatcher` (see https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/association_matcher.rb for complete list).

As a related aside which you may already be aware of, `distinct` does not ensure uniqueness of the relation, it only ensures that you get a distinct result set when you query.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer Peter. More Googling found more on the aside you mentioned. Will probably  Happy New Year.

Comment: As I recall, the only way to ensure uniqueness (i.e. avoiding race conditions) is to create an SQL index that guarantees it. If you find/found something different, would you mind letting me know? Thanks and HNY to you as well.

Comment: You're right. Everything I have found involves adding the unique constraint to my indexes. Thanks again.